# View ascx.cs files from deployed website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflector

I've got a website that I published on IIS, but it seems like I've got the wrong version of source code in my dev environment.
I just need the code from 1 ascx.cs file.

Can I get to the contents of an ascx.cs file from a deployed website?

I've tried using .NET Reflector as suggested on other posts, but it seems like this tool only gives me access to my normal classes and not to the .ascx.cs files.  Or am I just missing that?

EDIT:
Additional information as requested in answers.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="timesheet.ascx.cs" Inherits="controls_timesheet" %>
```

Comment: Why not just re deploy?

Comment: The site that is deployed contains code that is not in my dev environment.  Something went missing, and I just want to recover that code.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the DLL of the compiled web site to get the class that represents your .ascx.cs file.

For example, if your project is called MyWebSiteProject, you should have a MyWebSiteProject.dll on your /bin folder.

Open this DLL with .net Reflector, or http://ilspy.net/, if your control is named MyUserControl, it should be inside the namespace MyWebSiteProject.

Please double check your project's and controls namespace first.

Hope this helps, good luck :)

Comment: Thanks, but sadly I don't see that DLL in .NET Reflector.  I do have App-Code.dll.  Maybe I can also mention it's a website and not a web project.  But I'm sure the answer will help someone else.  +1 for that.  In the mean time I decided to rewrite that code.  Let's hope it's the same.

Comment: umm, a website, and it's been precompiled, i would guess it would be within the app-code.dll, but i've never done that. Actually could you edit your question with the <%@ Control of the .ascx file? The inherits attribute should indicate the class name and namespace.

Comment: Deployed website probably the correct terminology rather than precompiled.  Have changed it.

Comment: if you open all DLLs with ilspy, please search for "controls_timesheet" (without the ") that should definately be in one of the DLLs, otherwise it wouldn't be working